# How to get a change log of updgraded dependencies?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there some change log to check what is updated the last days?

We used composer to update modules, but we are looking for a way to see what exactly was changed the last days.

Can we check this somewhere?

Comment: @yivi Sorry, in our dependencies. So when we run the composer update command, to check what is exactly updated the last days.

Comment: @yivi Thanks! I know and that is exactly the log we need but then from a couple days ago. Any idea how to get this one?

Comment: You can simply do `composer update --no-ansi &> update.log` each time, and store the results. But composer does not keep a log of past runs.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! In that case we can store the update. Good to keep a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer does not store a record of what installs at every time. It simply updates `composer.lock` with the discrete package versions that were installed.

Since usually `composer.lock` is stored under a version control system such as git, it tends to be enough. If you want to have an easier way to check what specific versions are installed on different updates, you could always store the result of `update` on file to see what was upgraded to what:

```
composer update --no-ansi &> update.log
```

Or maybe more practical, run `composer info > installed.txt` and commit that file after each `update` or `require`. That way you would have an easy to read and easy to diff file to see what versions were installed along the project lifetime.